# Почему нет правого маргина у красного блока, хотя в блочной модели написано, что правый маргин 10 пикселей?

Tags: css, css3

Привет.

Вопрос по CSS. Написал разметку:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Если это дело открыть в девтулс, то видно это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, почему нет правого `margin` у красного блока, хотя в блочной модели написано, что `margin-right: 10px`?

Почему нижний и верхний `margin` короткие? Видно, что они не доходят до правого края красного блока.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем примере красный блок вылез за пределы боди и не был обрезан, так как я не задавал `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Формула горизонтального форматирования для блочного элемента:

   *width(родителя) = margin-left(потомка) + border-left(потомка) + padding-left(потомка) +
       width(потомка) + padding-right(потомка) + border-right(потомка) + margin-right(потомка)*
2. Когда левый *margin-left* не авто, *width* не авто и *margin-right* не авто, то *margin-right* сбрасывается в ноль, чтобы дополнить нужную длину по формуле.
3. В данном примере нет рамки и паддингов.

По этой формуле:

1097 пикселей = 10 пикселей + 1097 пикселей + x

x=-10 пикселей, то есть, **правый маргин равен -10 пикселей**. Браузер врет, когда пишет, что правый маргин равен 10 пикселей

Answer (score 1):

Потому что установлена ширина 100%. Блочный элемент по умолчанию и так 100%. У вас 100% рассчитывается из размера родителя, а это вся ширина body.

Уберите у #one 100%, ну и html с body незачем.

И еще лучше не использовать обнуление стилей браузера подобным методом.

Почитайте тут: 
https://habrahabr.ru/post/45296/

Comment: при чем тут ширина содержимого?. вопрос в том ,почему правого маргина нет. вообще-то, у блочного элемента по умолчанию width:auto

Comment: Уберите width: 100%; у #one 
Потому что слева на право браузер считает. У вас слева отступ 10px уже и ширина как у родителя.

Добавьте для body { owerflow: scroll; } Это будет наглядней.

Comment: не надо ничего убирать. я и так знаю, что, если справа и слева маргины заданы, а видз в авто стоит, то ширина содержимого подгонится так, чтобы вместе с левым и правым маргинами заполнить содержимое родителя полностью. вопрос в том, почему в данном случае нет правого маргина и почему верхний и нижний маргины не достают до правого края красного блока

Comment: Не хватает ему места на экране.

Comment: @Dimon там есть правый `margin`. И отступы сверху и снизу правильно отображаются. Штука в том, что у вас получается 10рх отступ слева + 100% ширина блока + 10рх отступ справа. На разрешении родительского блока в 1000рх, вы получите общую ширину в 1020рх. При этом сам блок будет смещен относительно родителя на 10рх право, что и видно на вашем скрине.

Comment: я навел на маргины, верхний, нижний и левый подсвечиваются оранжевым, видно что они реально есть. а правым маргин не подсвечивается

Answer (score 1):

Вот ваш код для наглядности:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#one {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  
  float: left
}

#one_plus {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  
  float: left
}

#two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="one_plus"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Как видите, там есть отступ. Но, когда вы делаете ширину у первого блока 100%, он использует ширину родительского окна и смещается вправо из-за `margin-left`. Этот блок выходит за пределы родительского блока. Естественно, при этом не будет видно отступ справа.

Так ведут себя блоки в вашем примере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Этот блок выходит за пределы родительского блока. Естественно, при этом не будет видно отступ справа." - мне не понятно, почему при этом не будет видно отступ справа. что красный блок выходит за пределы боди - это понятно

Comment: А как будет видно отступ, если даже куска самого блока не видно? Если вы хотите, чтоб он был вписан в body и имел отступы сбоку, нужно иначе делать разметку.

Comment: куска блока будет не видно только тогда, когда эти три дива положить в блок-контейнер, которому задать overflow:hidden. а на моем примере красный блок вылез за пределы боди и не был обрезан, так как я не задавал overflow:hidden. я добавил в вопросе картинку, которая это показывает

Comment: я думаю, что ответ такой: если произошло переполнение, например, блок 1 вылез за пределы блока-родителя 2, то вылезшую часть блока 1 вообще никто из других блоков в документе не "видит" - вылезшая часть может накладываться на другие блоки. а раз никто не видит, то вообще нет смысла отображать маргины, которые служат для создания зазоров между рамками блоков. то есть, маргин есть, но браузер его просто не отображает, потому что нет смысла - часть блока вылезла наружу блока-родителя, а другие блоки вылезшую часть не видят и маргин тоже не видят

Comment: Надеюсь вы сами понимаете, что пишите. А то я совсем ничего не понял. `margin` создает отступ за пределами блока. За пределами `<body>` соседние элементы отображаться не будут, а значит и отступ там не видно. Он там попросту не нужен.

Comment: я правильно написал. это надо на отдельном примере показывать. я этот пример уже написал. если хотите, можем в чате обсудить

Comment: В этом нет необходимости. Если мы оба понимаем принцип работы описанный в примере, то и обсуждать тут нечего.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52325/discussion-between-dimon-and-alexey-giryayev).

Comment: сделал пример. в нем блок выпирает за пределы бади, но маргины всеравно отображаются